# Do VPN and SSH reverse port forwarding achieve the same thing?

Tags: ssh, vpn, port-forwarding

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network

> A virtual private network (VPN) extends a private network across a public network, and enables users to send and receive data across shared or public networks **as if their computing devices were directly connected to the private network**.

A machine outside a private network can access the hosts inside the private network, using SSH reverse port forwarding.

Do VPN and SSH reverse port forwarding achieve the same thing?

SSH works in the application layer of the IP/TCP model. Does VPN also  work in the application layer of the IP/TCP model?

Thanks.

Comment: Although VPN protocols are application layer protocol, but it's not proper to say VPN works at which layer. They basically encrypt and encapusle IP packet into TCP or UDP packet using its own VPN protocol. Pretty much like SSH tunnel except they encapusle IP packets instead of just TCP-based application layer data. Notice how different IP is from TCP, it doesn't have the concept of connection, so there's no concept of multiplexing in VPN.

Comment: Thanks.  If you look at some quote from Tanenbaum's book here (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/506804/674), is a VPN which is built using firewall and IPsec  still at  the application layer?  Is a VPN which is built using MPLS  still at  the application layer?